# Sqlite - join results from different queries

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have table like this (short brief).

```
error_code  |  timestamp(ISO string)
```

For every error_code a timestamp is added.
I want to count all error codes and get something like this(using just one query):

```
error_code, count(error_code), sorted_timestamp
```

So I want to count all error occurence and get time stamp of last row inserted.

Any advice ?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: @redneb Yes, but I tried with JOIN and I found some problems there. Solution provided by Tim works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT error_code,
       COUNT(*) AS error_count,
       MAX(timestamp) AS latest_timestamp
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY error_code
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Your solution works perfectly. I tried with JOIN but I forgot about something like MAX.